# Were the sets of the 1964 movie "Mary Poppins" intended to look like a Broadway Show?

Tags: production, mary-poppins

I once heard someone say that the filmmakers of [*Mary Poppins* (1964)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0058331/) didn't try to make the sets look real and that they wanted the sets to look like they were straight out of a Broadway stage show, not a realistic movie. Is this true?

Comment: Can you elaborate on where you heard this? (A friend, a documentary etc.) It might help others find an answer if they know what your source was.

Answer (score 3):

### False

Most sets from those days were either done on a studio backlot or inside a studio.  As it were, Carroll Clark and William H. Tuntke were nominated for an [Academy Award for Art Direction](http://awardsdatabase.oscars.org/Search/GetResults?query=%7B%22IsHyperlinkQuery%22:true,%22FilmId%22:2906,%22Sort%22:%222-Film%20Title-Alpha%22,%22Search%22:%22Basic%22%7D) for their work on Mary Poppins, which was, in fact, shot entirely inside of a studio.  When you're working indoors, and using the technology of the time, you have the unfortunate effect of making the scenes look like a Broadway play due to the fluorescent lighting involved.  However, as much attention as possible was given to make it look realistic.

According to page 11 of a research paper on [The Making of Mary Poppins](https://www.ntschools.org/cms/lib/NY19000908/Centricity/Domain/750/Mary%20Poppins.pdf):

> Like most Hollywood musicals throughout the 1950's, all of *Mary
>   Poppins* was shot indoors, necessitating some fairly massive sets. 
>   The exteriors for Cherry Tree Lane and the park across the street were
>   all housed in soundstage number three on the Disney lot, which had
>   originally been built for *Darby O'Gill and the Little People*.  The
>   stage was the studio's largest, but it was still a tight fit trying to
>   pack in everything that was needed.
>
> ---
>
> A painted backing finished off the set.  "There was a mist over the
>   whole thing," adds Tuntke, "and you could put a little smoke in front
>   of it and it blended together with the mist on the backing.  It worked
>   out very well"